# How to read text file in Andorid from github

Tags: android, textview

I am a new learner of Android Studio. As my client request, he wants me to put the txt file into Github. What he wants me to do is read the file's content in my application. I know how to use raw and textview to read the content of the file in my project. But I cannot find a way to read it on Github. The purpose of this is to let him update the file.

Comment: That's really not the easiest way of doing things.  It would be far easier to just put it on a webserver somewhere at a known URL and download it from there.

Comment: It is not clear what is the purpose of the file. Do you show the text in your app? is it related to your app at all? is it some sort of wiki? Please edit your question

Comment: What I want is to show the content of txt file on Github on my Android application. I tried some ways like use bufferreader or URL textview to deal with that. But it can not worked.